# How do i console into a 3com 4500g switch?

Tags: switch, 3-com

I am using a USB to console and changed the rate on it to 19200 data 8 and stop rate 1 and i cant connect console in ? nothing appears on Tera term or putty.
i don't know if i am doing it right.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to drop it down to 9600 Baud, 8N1 should be alright, but some devices doesn't want to play nice at higher Baud rates, and 9600 8N1 seems to be somewhat of an industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

19200 Bd 8N1 (8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit) seems OK. Make sure you've

- selected the correct serial interface in the terminal software
- got a suitable console cable
- deactivated hardware flow control
- hit [Return] a couple of times

If the switch is configured for a specific speed you'll have to match that.